# gtk-why back button click signal handler is not called

Tags: c, linux, button, gtk

I have a notebook with 5 pages. Each Page has a liststore treeview and back button.

Originally back button is hidden. When you click an item of treeview, it searches nearest Bluetooth devices and returns a new treeview. But clicking back button should go back to the previous list. It is not going. the `printf` in back handler is also not getting called.
my code is:-

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>
#include <glib.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <bluetooth/bluetooth.h>
#include <bluetooth/hci.h>
#include <bluetooth/hci_lib.h>
GtkWidget *scrolledwindow;
GtkWidget *backbutton;
struct param
{
    GtkWidget* backbutton;
    GtkWidget* Okbutton;
    GtkWidget* scrolledwindow;
    GtkWidget*newChild;
    GtkWidget*oldChild;
};


struct BTDeviceDetails
{
    char*addr;
    char*name;
};
struct node
{
    struct node* next;
    struct BTDeviceDetails * data;
};

void insertNode(struct node ** start,struct BTDeviceDetails* resultData)
{
    struct node * temp = *start;
    printf("insert node\n");
    if(*start==0)
    {
        *start = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
        (*start)->next = 0;
        (*start)->data = resultData;
        return;
    }
    for(;temp->next!=0;temp=temp->next);
    printf("inserted %s",resultData->name);
    temp->next = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    temp->next->next = 0;
    temp->next->data = resultData;
}

void emptyList(struct node * start)
{
    if(start == 0)
    {
       return; 
    }
    struct node * temp = start->next;
    for(;temp!=0;temp = temp->next)
    {
        free(start->data->addr);
        free(start->data->name);
        free(start->data);
        free(start);
        start = temp;
    }
    free(start->data->addr);
    free(start->data->name);
    free(start->data);
    free(start);
    start = 0;
}


GtkWidget * init_tree();
GtkWidget * init_tree2(struct node ** start);
static void destroy(GtkWidget *widget, gpointer data)
{
  gtk_main_quit();
}


void deviceDiscovery(struct node** start)
{
    inquiry_info *ii = NULL;
    int max_rsp, num_rsp;
    int dev_id, sock, len, flags;
    int i;
    char addr[19] = { 0 };
    char name[248] = { 0 };

    dev_id = hci_get_route(NULL);
    sock = hci_open_dev( dev_id );
    if (dev_id < 0 || sock < 0) {
        perror("opening socket");
        exit(1);
    }

    len  = 8;
    max_rsp = 255;
    flags = IREQ_CACHE_FLUSH;
    ii = (inquiry_info*)malloc(max_rsp * sizeof(inquiry_info));

    num_rsp = hci_inquiry(dev_id, len, max_rsp, NULL, &ii, flags);
    if( num_rsp < 0 ) perror("hci_inquiry");

    for (i = 0; i < num_rsp; i++) {
        ba2str(&(ii+i)->bdaddr, addr);
        memset(name, 0, sizeof(name));
        if (hci_read_remote_name(sock, &(ii+i)->bdaddr, sizeof(name), 
            name, 0) < 0)
        strcpy(name, "[unknown]");
        struct BTDeviceDetails* resultData = (struct BTDeviceDetails *)malloc(sizeof(struct BTDeviceDetails)); 
        resultData->addr = (char*)malloc((strlen(addr)+1)*sizeof(char));
        resultData-> name = (char*)malloc((strlen(name)+1)*sizeof(char));
        strcpy(resultData->addr,addr);
        strcpy(resultData-> name,name);
        insertNode(start,resultData);
        printf("%s  %s\n", addr, name);
    }

    free( ii );
    close( sock );
//    return 0;
}


static void Back (GtkButton *button, gpointer   user_data)
{
      printf("inside back handle\n");
      struct param* parameters = (struct param*)user_data;
      gtk_widget_hide(GTK_WIDGET(parameters->scrolledwindow));
      gtk_container_remove(GTK_CONTAINER(parameters->scrolledwindow), GTK_WIDGET(parameters->newChild));
      gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(parameters->scrolledwindow), parameters->oldChild);
      gtk_widget_hide (GTK_WIDGET(parameters->backbutton));
      gtk_widget_show_all (GTK_WIDGET(parameters->scrolledwindow));
}

static void Ok (GtkButton *button, gpointer   user_data)
{

}

static void replace_tab(GtkTreeView *tree_view, GtkTreePath *path, GtkTreeViewColumn *column, gpointer user_data)
{
      struct param* parameters = (struct param*)user_data;
      gchar *string;
      GtkTreeIter iter;
      GtkTreeModel *model = gtk_tree_view_get_model (tree_view);
      gtk_tree_model_get_iter(model, &iter, path); 
      gtk_tree_model_get (model, &iter, 0, &string, -1);
      g_print ("activated: %s\n", string);
      if(!strcmp(string,"Register"))
      {
          struct node * start = 0;
          deviceDiscovery(&start);
          parameters->newChild =  init_tree2(&start);
          g_signal_connect(backbutton, "clicked", G_CALLBACK(Back), (gpointer) parameters);
          //GtkWidget* liststore = GTK_WIDGET(gtk_tree_view_get_model(tree_view));
          gtk_widget_hide(GTK_WIDGET(parameters->scrolledwindow));
          gtk_container_remove(GTK_CONTAINER(parameters->scrolledwindow), GTK_WIDGET(tree_view));
          gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(parameters->scrolledwindow), parameters->newChild);
          gtk_widget_show (GTK_WIDGET(parameters->backbutton));
          //gtk_widget_show (GTK_WIDGET(parameters->Okbutton));
          gtk_widget_show_all (GTK_WIDGET(parameters->scrolledwindow));

      }
      else if(!strcmp(string,"New Configuration"))
      {

      }
      else if(!strcmp(string,"Edit Configuration"))
      {

      }
      else if(!strcmp(string,"Delete Configuration"))
      {

      }
      else if(!strcmp(string,"Add location to turn-off place list"))
      {

      }
      else if(!strcmp(string,"Disable Turn-off Places"))
      {

      }
      else if(!strcmp(string,"Enable Turn-off Places"))
      {

      }
      else if(!strcmp(string,"Disable Distance"))
      {

      }

      else if(!strcmp(string,"Enable Distance"))
      {

      }
      else if(!strcmp(string,"Factory Reset"))
      {

      }
}

GtkWidget * init_tree()
{

    GtkListStore *liststore = gtk_list_store_new(1, G_TYPE_STRING);
    GtkTreeIter treeiter;

    gtk_list_store_append(liststore, &treeiter);
    gtk_list_store_set(liststore, &treeiter, 0, "Register", -1);
    gtk_list_store_append(liststore, &treeiter);
    gtk_list_store_set(liststore, &treeiter, 0, "New Configuration", -1);
    gtk_list_store_append(liststore, &treeiter);
    gtk_list_store_set(liststore, &treeiter, 0, "Edit Configuration", -1);
    gtk_list_store_append(liststore, &treeiter);
    gtk_list_store_set(liststore, &treeiter, 0, "Delete Configuration", -1);
    gtk_list_store_append(liststore, &treeiter);
    gtk_list_store_set(liststore, &treeiter, 0, "Add location to turn-off place list", -1);
    gtk_list_store_append(liststore, &treeiter);
    gtk_list_store_set(liststore, &treeiter, 0, "Disable Turn-off Places", -1);
    gtk_list_store_append(liststore, &treeiter);
    gtk_list_store_set(liststore, &treeiter, 0, "Enable Turn-off Places", -1);
    gtk_list_store_append(liststore, &treeiter);
    gtk_list_store_set(liststore, &treeiter, 0, "Disable Distance", -1);
    gtk_list_store_append(liststore, &treeiter);
    gtk_list_store_set(liststore, &treeiter, 0, "Enable Distance", -1);
    gtk_list_store_append(liststore, &treeiter);
    gtk_list_store_set(liststore, &treeiter, 0, "Factory Reset", -1);
    gtk_list_store_append(liststore, &treeiter);
    GtkWidget *treeview = gtk_tree_view_new_with_model(GTK_TREE_MODEL(liststore));

    GtkCellRenderer *cellrenderertext = gtk_cell_renderer_text_new();

    GtkTreeViewColumn *treeviewcolumn = gtk_tree_view_column_new_with_attributes("Settings",
                                                                                 cellrenderertext,
                                                                                 "text", 0,
                                                                                 NULL);
    gtk_tree_view_append_column(GTK_TREE_VIEW(treeview), treeviewcolumn);

    return treeview;
}

GtkWidget * init_tree2(struct node** start)
{

    GtkListStore *liststore = gtk_list_store_new(1, G_TYPE_STRING);
    GtkTreeIter treeiter;
    if(*start ==0) printf("\nfailure\n");
    struct node * temp = *start;
    for(;temp!=0; temp = temp->next)
    {
        gtk_list_store_append(liststore, &treeiter);
        gtk_list_store_set(liststore, &treeiter, 0, temp->data->name, -1);
    }
    gtk_list_store_append(liststore, &treeiter);
    gtk_list_store_set(liststore, &treeiter, 0, "b", -1);
    gtk_list_store_append(liststore, &treeiter);
    gtk_list_store_set(liststore, &treeiter, 0, "c", -1);
    gtk_list_store_append(liststore, &treeiter);
    gtk_list_store_set(liststore, &treeiter, 0, "d", -1);
    gtk_list_store_append(liststore, &treeiter);
    gtk_list_store_set(liststore, &treeiter, 0, "e", -1);
    gtk_list_store_append(liststore, &treeiter);
    gtk_list_store_set(liststore, &treeiter, 0, "f", -1);
    gtk_list_store_append(liststore, &treeiter);
    gtk_list_store_set(liststore, &treeiter, 0, "Aptosid", -1);
    gtk_list_store_append(liststore, &treeiter);
    gtk_list_store_set(liststore, &treeiter, 0, "OpenSuSE", -1);
    gtk_list_store_append(liststore, &treeiter);
    gtk_list_store_set(liststore, &treeiter, 0, "Linux Mint", -1);

    gtk_list_store_append(liststore, &treeiter);
    gtk_list_store_set(liststore, &treeiter, 0, "Arch Linux", -1);

    GtkWidget *treeview = gtk_tree_view_new_with_model(GTK_TREE_MODEL(liststore));

    GtkCellRenderer *cellrenderertext = gtk_cell_renderer_text_new();

    GtkTreeViewColumn *treeviewcolumn = gtk_tree_view_column_new_with_attributes("BTDevices",
                                                                                 cellrenderertext,
                                                                                 "text", 0,
                                                                                 NULL);
    gtk_tree_view_append_column(GTK_TREE_VIEW(treeview), treeviewcolumn);

    return treeview;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  gtk_init(&argc, &argv);

  GtkWidget *window = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
  gtk_window_set_default_size(GTK_WINDOW(window), 200, 200);
  g_signal_connect(window, "destroy", G_CALLBACK(destroy), NULL);

  GtkWidget *notebook = gtk_notebook_new();
  gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(window), notebook);


  int count;
  gchar *text;

  for (count = 1; count <= 5; count++)
    {
      text = g_strdup_printf("Page %d", count);
      GtkWidget *label = gtk_label_new(text);

      GtkWidget *vbox = gtk_box_new(GTK_ORIENTATION_VERTICAL, 5);
      GtkWidget *scrolledwindow = gtk_scrolled_window_new(NULL, NULL);

      backbutton = gtk_button_new_with_label ("Back");
      gtk_widget_set_no_show_all (backbutton, TRUE);

      //GtkWidget *Okbutton = gtk_button_new_with_label ("Ok");
      //gtk_widget_set_no_show_all (Okbutton, TRUE);

      gtk_box_pack_start (GTK_BOX(vbox), scrolledwindow, TRUE, TRUE, 0);
      gtk_box_pack_end (GTK_BOX(vbox), backbutton, FALSE, FALSE, 0);
      //gtk_box_pack_end (GTK_BOX(vbox), Okbutton, FALSE, FALSE, 0);


      GtkWidget* treeview = init_tree();
      //GtkWidget* treeview2 = init_tree2();
      struct param* parameters = malloc(sizeof(struct param));
      parameters->backbutton = backbutton;
      //parameters->Okbutton = Okbutton;
      parameters->scrolledwindow = scrolledwindow;
      parameters->oldChild= treeview;
      //parameters->newChild= treeview2;

      g_signal_connect(treeview, "row-activated", G_CALLBACK(replace_tab), (gpointer) parameters);
      //g_signal_connect(Okbutton, "clicked", G_CALLBACK(Ok), (gpointer) parameters);

      gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(scrolledwindow), treeview);
      gtk_notebook_append_page(GTK_NOTEBOOK(notebook), vbox, label);
    }

  gtk_widget_show_all(window);

  gtk_main();

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: You are using the uninitialized global `backbutton` rather than `parameters->backbutton", that seems very fishy.

Comment: Your code was already a bit large for a MCVE in your previous question and gets larger and larger. To show your problem there is no need to add that many items to your list view or to include any of your Bluetooth stuff. Please consider removing parts that are not related to your problem.